# Can randomly losing connection to a specific webaddress indicate DNS issues?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

We use an on-premise Multi Factor Authentication server that communicates with 2 webservers:

- pfd.phonefactor.net
- pfd2.phonefactor.net

Usually there are no issues, but sometimes the server will randomly be unable to connect to these web addresses, returning a 404.

Trying to browse to one of 2 websites on my own workstation (same network, same domain) will work as usual. Usually after a short period, the web adresses will start working on the MFA server as well.

Does anyone have an idea of what could cause this? I've already tried disabling our AntiVirus and confirmed our hardware firewall is not blocking traffic

Comment: A 404 error is indicating that SOME webserver is being reached - maybe not the one you want.  Have you checked your webserver logs to see if you find 404 responses that correlate with the incidents on the MFA server?

Comment: Hi Brandon, the only logs I can think of to use are the MFA logs themselves, which don't really tell me anything except that they are trying to reach said webaddresses and are unsuccesful. Do you have any recommendations where to look?

Comment: Despite the fact that 404 error is a client-side error, I suppose you'll have to check your webservers logs as well.

Comment: Here's what you do:  Say for example you experience this problem on 1/1/18 at 10:03am.  Reach to whomever manages the phonefactor.net servers and say "I saw some 404 errors from your sites on 1/1/18 @ 10:103am.  Can you check the server logs and help me debug this?"  He should be able to look at his logs and verify the 404s did indeed come from his servers, and probably details about what caused the "not found" (the standard reason for a 404) errors.

Comment: Hi Brandon, I get what you mean. Unfortunately, Phonefactor is owned by Microsoft (MFA is their authentication service) and I have no way to connect the right technical department. I'll give it another shot but in the meantime, do you have other recommendations?